# Calling UWP C# code from UWP c++/cx

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I have an UWP C++/cx application and UWP C# class library.
How can i use classes from c# library in c++ project?

- C++/CLI not supported by UWP apps so i cant make c++/cli wrapper.
- Im not sure but looks like COM wrapping isnt an option in UWP world.
- Reverse P/Invoke is not an option as host application is c++
- Windows Runtime Component also will require kind of callback from C# code,
  but it can be instantiated in c++ code only.

Any suggestions?

P.S.
I cannot have "c# proxy app", my app is of type c++/cx.

Comment: Why can you not access your UWP class library from C++/CX?

Comment: I can add classlib reference to c++ application but it not affect anything. I dont see classlib namespaces and classes. However, they are public. May be i misses something obvious?

Comment: [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx)

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" in your question. Post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Standart uwp c# classlibrary is invisible for c++/cx.
Proxy library "windows runtime component" should be created and added to c++ class.

Answer (score 0):

For a great example of how to do this, check out how ChakraBridge C++/CX project in React Native Windows is used:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/tree/master/ReactWindows/ChakraBridge

C# calls into C++/CX and then back out, totally transparently, living up to the cross-language workflow the CLR allows. There's also a pull request in React Native Windows that shows how to add a few compile-time directives that allows for sharing C++/CX and C++/CLI code:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/pull/769/